# Comparing dates in a cell

Tags: datetime, google-sheets

I am trying to do a sumifs in Google Sheets that sums based on a number of variables held in cells.  I want to be able to vary the dates in two cells to change the range that is summed.  My formula looks like:

```
 =SUMIFS(D2:D500,A2:A500,">8/01/15",A2:A500,"<9/01/15",F2:F500,C1012)
```

I want to be able to replace the two dates with cells.  When I do, I get a formula parse error.  I have seen a lot of questions about doing this for formatting, but not in this context.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your dates are in I1 and J1 please try:

```
=SUMIFS(D2:D500,A2:A500,">"&I1,A2:A500,"<"&J1,F2:F500,C1012)
```